# How to pass model fields to a JsonResponse object

Tags: python, json, django, httpresponse

Django 1.7 introduced the [JsonResponse objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), which I try to use to return a list of values to my ajax request.

I want to pass

```
>>> Genre.objects.values('name', 'color')
[{'color': '8a3700', 'name': 'rock'}, {'color': 'ffff00', 'name': 'pop'}, {'color': '8f8f00', 'name': 'electronic'}, {'color': '9e009e', 'name': 'chillout'}, {'color': 'ff8838', 'name': 'indie'}, {'color': '0aff0a', 'name': 'techno'}, {'color': 'c20000', 'name': "drum'n'bass"}, {'color': '0000d6', 'name': 'worldmusic'}, {'color': 'a800a8', 'name': 'classic'}, {'color': 'dbdb00', 'name': 'hiphop'}]
```

to a JsonResponse object.

However, my attempts fail.

```
>>> JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar', 'blib': 'blab'}) # works
<django.http.response.JsonResponse object at 0x7f53d28bbb00>

>>> JsonResponse(Genre.objects.values('name', 'color')) # doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marcel/Dokumente/django/FlushFM/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 476, in __init__
    raise TypeError('In order to allow non-dict objects to be '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False
```

This is probably due to the different data structure of `Genre.objects.values()`.

How would this be done right?

[edit]

With `safe=False` I get

```
>>> JsonResponse(Genre.objects.values('name', 'color'), safe=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marcel/Dokumente/django/FlushFM/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 479, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/marcel/Dokumente/django/FlushFM/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 109, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [{'color': '8a3700', 'name': 'rock'}, {'color': 'ffff00', 'name': 'pop'}, {'color': '8f8f00', 'name': 'electronic'}, {'color': '9e009e', 'name': 'chillout'}, {'color': 'ff8838', 'name': 'indie'}, {'color': '0aff0a', 'name': 'techno'}, {'color': 'c20000', 'name': "drum'n'bass"}, {'color': '0000d6', 'name': 'worldmusic'}, {'color': 'a800a8', 'name': 'classic'}, {'color': 'dbdb00', 'name': 'hiphop'}] is not JSON serializable
```

What works is

```
>>> JsonResponse(list(Genre.objects.values('name', 'color')), safe=False)
<django.http.response.JsonResponse object at 0x7f53d28bb9e8>
```

But isn't there a better way to generate a dict out of a Model object?

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message says?

Comment: @DanielRoseman well yes, but also setting `safe=False` would result in an error message. Do you need the output?

Comment: @speendo Is it the same error with `safe=False` as well? Perhaps try it after passing the `ValuesQuerySet` to `list()`: `JsonResponse(list(Genre.objects.values('name', 'color')))`

Comment: with `list()` *and* `safe=False` it would work. But wouldn't it be better to pass a dict-object? Is there a way to convert `Genre.objects.values()` to a valid dict object?

Comment: @speendo: .values() returns a list of dictionaries. If you want you can create a new dictionary `dict(genres=Genre.objects...)` and use that instead.

Comment: @Tiago thank you, but `>>> JsonResponse(dict(genres=Genre.objects.values('name', 'color')))` is also "not JSON serializable" :(

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but maybe now the `list()` will do the trick. `dict(genres=list(Genre.object...))`.

Comment: @Tiago indeed. Is it just me, or is it ridiculously tricky to generate a JSON response object out of a django model? Anyway - would you like to formulate an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For future reference, `.values()` returns a `ValuesQuerySet` that behaves like a iterable full of dictionaries, so using the `list()` will make a new instance of a `list` with all the dictionaries in it. With that, you can create a new dict and serialize that.

```
response = JsonResponse(dict(genres=list(Genre.objects.values('name', 'color'))))
```

IIRC, it's not safe to have a JSON object that has a list as root and that's probably why Django is complaining. I couldn't find any reference about that now to provide a source, sorry.

Comment: The answer over at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26833156/179583 uses `serializers` from django.core, which might be handy to get the entire model out but seems odd/gross to have to pass already-serialized JSON to JsonResponse. I like this answer's technique better, especially for when I only need a few fields from each model.

Comment: I've been looking so long for an answer like this!

Comment: In the serialize function you can pass an optional `fields` parameter which will only return the specified fields instead of the whole object as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

To pass nondictionary values to the JsonResponse as you retrieved with `Genres.object.values('name','color')` you can simple set the safe argument to false and it will return JSON.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def django_json(request):
    data = Genres.object.values('name','color')
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

That should return a list of JSON of the values you specified. Check out my article [How to Return a Json Response with Django](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-return-a-json-response-in-django/) for more detailed info on how this works.

Alternatively, if you would like to return a queryset back as JSON you can use Djangos core serializer like this:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Genre

def django_models_json(request):
    qs = Genre.objects.all()
    data = serialize("json", qs, fields=('name', 'color'))
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

This will return the same as above.