# Use JSONResponse to serialize a QuerySet in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, ajax, django, jsonresponse

I saw that now in Django 1.7 I can use the `http.JSONResponse` object to send JSON to a client. My View is:

```
#Ajax
def get_chat(request):
    usuario = request.GET.get('usuario_consultor', None)
    usuario_chat = request.GET.get('usuario_chat', None)

    mensajes = list(MensajeDirecto.objects.filter(Q(usuario_remitente = usuario, usuario_destinatario = usuario_chat) | Q(usuario_remitente = usuario_chat, usuario_destinatario = usuario)))


    return JsonResponse(mensajes, safe=False)
```

But I get the next error:

> <MensajeDirecto: Towi CrisTowi> is not JSON serializable`

Do you know how to serialize a QuerySet to send it back in JSON form?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067369/how-to-pass-model-fields-to-a-jsonresponse-object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_chat(request):
    usuario = request.GET.get('usuario_consultor', None)
    usuario_chat = request.GET.get('usuario_chat', None)

    mensajes = MensajeDirecto.objects.filter(Q(usuario_remitente = usuario, usuario_destinatario = usuario_chat) | Q(usuario_remitente = usuario_chat, usuario_destinatario = usuario))

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', mensajes), safe=False)
```

Ref:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/

Comment: We can also use HttpResponse instead of JsonResponse:

return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', mensajes))

Comment: @jatin You do want to use JsonResponse to ensure that the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`.

Comment: `return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', data), safe=False)` returns me JSON String instead of JSON...
`return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', data), content_type="application/json")` works sell.

Comment: @Arst JsonResponse is a subclass of HttpResponse with the `content_type` parameter already preset to `application/json`. Thus using a HttpResponse is essentially manually constructing a similar result. Perhaps look for another cause if the header isn't being set.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: @Arst is correct. If you use `JsonResponse`, you're essentially re-serializing an already JSON string. See my answer below.

Comment: `serializers` is a stupid class, which not suitable with `JsonResponse`. it doing to much, return dumped `json` string instead of dict. the answer below is correct. Developers have to set mime manually.

Answer (score 69):

You shouldn't re-serialize with `JsonResponse`. You'll get a correctly formatted JSON response with:

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    my_model = MyModel.objects.all()
    response = serializers.serialize("json", my_model)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

If you use a `JsonResponse`, it will coerce the already serialized JSON to a string, which is probably not what you want.

*Note: Works with Django 1.10*

Comment: Works like a charm on django 1.11

Comment: And with Django 2. Thanks!

Comment: Best answer. I got error with JsonResponse. It returns as string for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need serialize. It will mangle the data, add a bunch of useless dictionary keys like model name, pk and fields.

instead of this

```
return JsonResponse(mensajes, safe=False)
```

just do this (mensajes = MensajeDirecto.objects.filter..)

```
return JsonResponse({"mensajes": list(mensajes.values())})
```

This way, you are not returning a list, you are returning a valid json, so you can use `safe=True` which is default. You can also return other messages to show on the frontend such as `{"mensajes": ..., "error": "invalid request" }`